# Save shapefiles from command line altering geometry type and disabling z-dimension?

Tags: geometry-conversion, save

I would like to use QGIS from Linux terminal to read a shapefile and save it as, with specific Geometry type instead of automatic and making sure z-dimension is not included.

How can I do that?

Comment: You would be better off using `ogr2ogr` for that

Comment: You can drop z but you can only write point, line, or polygon type shapefiles. I don't believe you can successfully select any other type than the automatically picked one. Please give more details if you have some issues.

Comment: The shapes are either line/polyline or polygon/multipolygon, there is not a mix of types.